# convert the binary data to readable text

Tags: angularjs, binary, etcd

when using the ETCD dashboard, we find a binary string like

```
var _deps_js = "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x09\x6e\x88\x00\xff\xcc\xbd\x7b\x77\xdb\x46\xb2\x2f\xfa\xff\xf9\x14\x22\xc6\x47\x01\xcc\x16\x25\xd9\x99\xb9\x7b\xc0\x40\xbc\x89\x1d\x27\xce\x24\x76\x26\x76\x26\x0f\x8a\xc9\xc2\x8b\x24\x24\x92\xa0\x49\xca\x92\x23\x72\x3e\xfb\xad\x5f\x55\x77\xa3\x01\x82\x72\xf6\xec\x7b\xd6\x3a\x99\xb1\x88\x47\xa3\x9f\xd5\xd5\xf5\xae\xce\xf8\x66\x91\x6e\x8a\x72\xe1\xc7\x2a\x09\xee\xbd\x32\xb9\xca\xd3\x8d\x17\x45\x9b\x0f\xcb\xbc\x1c\x1f\xcd\xcb\xec\x66\x96\x1f\x1f\x1f\x78\xd1\xcb\xef\x96\xe5\x6a\xb3\x1e\xd4\x6f\xa3\xb8\x97\x95\xe9\xcd\x3c\x5f\x6c\x06\x09\xd5\xdc\x39\x0b\xc2\xaa\xa1\xe0\xbe\x18\xfb\x9d\xaa\x48\xb0\x99\xae\xca\xdb\xa3\x45\x7e\x7b\xf4\xe5\x6a\x55\xae\x7c\xef\xea\x9f\x37\xf9\xea\xc3\xd1\x2a\x7f\x77\x53\xac\xf2\xf5\x51\x7c\x74\x5b\x2c\x32\x2a\x73\x5b\x6c\xa6\x74\x67\xbe\xf4\x82\xfe\x2a\xdf\xdc\xac\x16\x47\xd4\x4a\xb0\x0b\xf9\xaf\xef\xdd\x2c\xb2\x7c\x5c\x2c\xf2\xcc\xeb\x98\xee\xca\xf7\x03\xf9\x09\x37\xd3\x62\xad\xea\x23\x37\x77\x47\x29\x3a\xf8\x3e\x5e\x1d\x25\x34\x8a\x59\xbe\x98\x6c\xa6\x2a\x8d\xe2\xa4\x87\x9a\xe8\x9d\x6e\xd1\x33\x1f\xd0\x94\x44\xe9\x76\x4b\x05\x8a\xf5\x4f\x5c\x3d\x15\x1a\x74\xce\xc3\x73\x7a\x11\xf7\x16\x65\x96\xbf\xa5\x2f\x8f\x8f\x93\x41\xe7\x2c\xf4\xe2\xd5\x2a\xfe\xa0\xbf\x39\xa3\x9f\x64\xbb\xf5\x16\x37\xf3\x24\x5f\x55\x73\x9b\x50\xe1\x8b\x33\xfa\x73\x72\x7e\x54\x2c\x8e\xe2\x9d\xed\x5c\x86\xce\xaa\x94\x67\x90\x5b\x7c\x61\x06\x91\x04\x81\x9e\x0a\x7a\x3e\x59\xe5\x4b\x2a\xe
```

it's a long list.
Is there a tool to convert this into a readable text so that I can know the exact the content.

Answer (score 2):

The two leading bytes "\x1f\x8b" indicate the data is gzip compressed.
You can use whatever gzip/gunzip library/utility you have to decode it.

Following is an example using Perl.

> use IO::Uncompress::Gunzip;
>   my $in = "\x1f\x8b..."; # <- your string goes here
>   &IO::Uncompress::Gunzip::gunzip( \$in => \my $out );
>   print $out;

and it returns something like

```
!function(a,b){"object"==typeof module&&"object"==typeof module.exports?module.exports=a.document?b(a,!0):function(a){if(!a.document)throw new Error("jQuery requires a window with a document");return b(a)}:b(a)}("undefined"!=typeof window?window:this,function(a,b){function c(a){var b=a.length,c=ab.type(a);return"function"===c||ab.isWindow(a)?!1:1===a.nodeType&&b?!0:"array"===c||0===b||"number"==typeof b&&b>0&&b-1 in a}function d(a,b,c){if(ab.isFunction(b))return ab.grep
```

Since the string in your question is truncated, above output is truncated.